# Swift - Implementing multiple scrollViews

Tags: swift3, scrollview

I am creating a photo album app, in which a page should consist of multiple imageViews, each one within a scrollView, so each image placed within the page can be scrolled and zoomed (kind of like Instagram's Layout).
What is the best way of implementing this? using CollectionView seems a bit complicated as the spaces may vary, based on the template selected, but when I try using multiple scrollViews I have troubles referencing to each one within the delegate viewForZooming function. I have tried using an array of scrollViews, but the delegate function isn't being called.

[image: Page layout example]

```
func drawPage(pageID: Int) {

    var tempImagesArray = [UIImage]()
    var tempImageLocationsArray: [CGRect] = []

    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var imageView = UIImageView()

    if pageID == 1 {
        tempImagesArray = imagesArrayLeft
        tempImageLocationsArray = imageLocationsArrayLeft
    }
    else {
        tempImagesArray = imagesArrayRight
        tempImageLocationsArray = imageLocationsArrayRight
    }

    for i in 0...tempImagesArray.count - 1 {

        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: tempImageLocationsArray[i])
        scrollView.delegate = self

        let image = tempImagesArray[i]
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.frame = tempImageLocationsArray[i]
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        scrollView.contentSize = image.size
        scrollView.clipsToBounds = true
        scrollView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        scrollView.layer.borderWidth = 4.0

        let scrollViewFrame = scrollView.frame
        let scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / scrollView.contentSize.width
        let scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / scrollView.contentSize.height
        let minScale = min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0

        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0
        scrollView.zoomScale = minScale

        scrollViewsArray.append(scrollView)
        imageViewsArray.append(imageView)

        scrollViewsArray[scrollViewsArray.count - 1].delegate = self

        self.pageFrameView.addSubview(scrollView)

    }
}
```

And the delegate function:

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

    if scrollViewsArray.count > 0 {
        if scrollView == scrollViewsArray[0] {
            return self.imageViewsArray[0]
        }
        else {
            return self.imageViewsArray[0]
            }
    }

    return nil

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SORRY!!! But your question is the bit complex to understand. What I'll suggest you the best, for now, is that to **USE tag for every scroll views rather than putting them in array**.

> Regards,
>   Code Blizzard